# Is the first Russian satellite still beeping?

Tags: artificial-satellite, russia, spaceflight-firsts, roscosmos

The Russians were the first to launch a satellite into space - and it did one thing: beep. It would send out radio waves of nothing but beeps.

Still, it was a huge technological achievement. My question: **Is the Russian satellite still beeping? If so, how can I hear it?**

Comment: This question seems strange, even a cursory google of "beeping russian sattelite" brings one to the wikipedia article, which has the answer for it. No scrolling required. The time it took to even type this question would have been longer than finding the answer oneself.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No.  Sputnik 1 reentered on Jan 4, 1958, a few months after launch.  The batteries died and it stopped beeping about three weeks after launch.

Comment: Any sources for that?

Comment: @Undo: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sputnik_1

Comment: then where it is? is it on orbit or ...?

Comment: "Reentered" means its orbit decayed and it burned up in our atmosphere.  Various broken, charred pieces of it are likely at the bottom of the ocean somewhere.